# Can't switch to installed version of Node. Permissions denied

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

I have 14.16.0 installed and I want to make it my active version but I keep getting permission denied and I don't know how to fix it. I tried several other fixes from like 7 years ago because I can't find anything recent but no dice.

[image: error codes]

Comment: have you used `sudo`?

Comment: Try `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/lib/node_modules` and `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/include/node/`

Comment: @awesomemaker3000 I have. I still get those errors.

Comment: @TusharGupta-curioustushar I used those and still nothing unfortunately. I used `sudo n` and tried to change active version after that and still get the same errors.

Comment: @radbahi What is the command you are typing?

Comment: @awesomemaker3000 `sudo n` then i select the version i want to make active